# Protractor - handling of "then" promise to make them more readable

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am trying to make a sequence of promises into more readable form. 
Would need help and ideas how can I optimize my tests to make it more readable to any tester? 
This is from my test spec:

```
    it('Should perform login', function () {
    help.click(page_element.username).then(function(){  
  help.setValue(page_element.username,browser.params.login.user).then(function(){      help.setValue(pageLocators.password,browser.params.login.password).then(function() {
    help.click(pageLocators.buttonLoginSubmit);
    });                                                                                              
     });
    });
    });
```

-> help is another js file containing method: click, setValue with return.

I have other similar test specs which are using a lot of "then"s, making code look ugly.

What are the ways to reduce them except just removing them out? 
Are there any possibilities to handle these promises by try-catch or promise.all?
Please tell me how to do that as I am unable.

Comment: Write them in typescript so you can use `await`.

Comment: You should also strongly consider using consistent indentation to make code more readable.

Comment: @Dai I can use await even in js. But that doesn't resolve the problem. Also reports are not giving me relevant failure upon test fail. I am using jasmine spec reporter.

Comment: The introduction of `async/await` syntax was almost purely to improve the readability of promises which is your desired result so I think the answer below is the only accepting one for your question

Answer (score 3):

You can use async and await.

```
it('Should perform login', async function () {
    await help.click(page_element.username);
    await help.setValue(page_element.username,browser.params.login.user);
    await help.setValue(pageLocators.password,browser.params.login.password);
    await help.click(pageLocators.buttonLoginSubmit);
});
```